# Is correct bind concrete implementations?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, architecture, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 to build an abstract system. When a customer needs some specific implementation, I need to override some parts of the code.

What I'm thinking is something like this scenario:

A Controller depends on some custom Request (concrete) by default. When a customer asks me another business rule, I'd have to extend this custom Request and bind this child implementation to the parent. Do something like this on my Provider:

```
$this->app->bind(ParentImpl::class, ChildImpl::class);
```

Talking about software architecture concepts, can I do it? Is it correct?

[EDIT]

A concrete example, I have an action that uses a Request like this:

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{

   public function someAction(ParentRequest $request)
   {
       # perform action
   }

}
```

My Request have some business validation logic:

```
class ParentRequest extends Request
{

   public function rules()
   {
      return [
         'a_field' => 'required',
         'b_field' => 'max:100'
      ];
   }

}
```

Now everything works, my default system logic is ok! **But my software is a base to other projects**, we will use it via composer and at the final projects **just the specific code will belong to app path**.

When a customer ask for some modification of business logic we'll need to override the old. My question is: is it correct? Can I, conceptually talking, do something like this code below?

```
class ChildRequest extends ParentRequest
{

   public function rules()
   {
      return [
         'a_field' => '',
         'b_field' => 'max:255'
      ];
   }

}
```

And then, bind it to override all dependencies of the project:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

   public function register()
   {
      $this->app->bind(ParentImpl::class, ChildImpl::class);
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this question more specifically? Your explanation is far abstract to understand.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I edited it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking with a teacher of mine, he said I can't do a perfect job. I'll always have to re-work on it. What I asked maybe isn't a wrong pattern, but the concept of the software probably is wrong.

I'll make a lot of base packages in minor scale, in a way of let it easier to refactor. When some customer ask for a new feature or a new business rule I develop it.

Develop software extremely abstract maybe wrong. It can do everything and don't be specific for the customer's need. It always has to be analysed. There is no rule, every software is a different story